# Geometry distorting in Camera View

Tags: camera, eevee-render-engine, geometry, distort

I was doing a YouTube tutorial called [Easy Soft Body Simulation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LeO5eOunzeQ) and ran into an issue where the plane that I set up for the background is distorting in camera view.

It's a very simple set up with one plane for a wall and one for a floor. In the layout view, the wall is a solid 90 degree plane painted black, but when I put it in camera mode (using 50mm), the wall is shortened significantly and slanted back at an angle. To be clear, the wall is not slanted in any way other than in camera view.

[image]

Because of this, there is a small triangle that shows in the render, where the wall and floor meet. As soon as I move the camera even slightly, the issue vanishes, but reappears in camera mode.

Is this user error (me, the noob) or a bug of some kind?

[image]

Comment: Hi, no I was using 50mm - the same as the tutorial. Wouldn't a 5 or 15 mm lens be an extreme fisheye?  I think 50mm is supposed to be what the human eye sees naturally, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: I uploaded the file. Here's the link  (hope I'm doing this right):                          [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6400" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6400/)

Comment: Thanks Joe. Yeah close :) I've added the file link to your question body, added your focal length and also done some minor formatting to make the question more readable. Hope you agree that this is an improvement, otherwise just roll it back. Also please consider accepting *rjg's* answer if this solved your issue, by clicking the check mark button on the left side of the answer, see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers Btw: Since the focal length wasn't the issue I removed my comments, you can do that too to keep it clean. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a clipping issue. If you increase the far plane of the camera you will see the entire wall.

[image: Clipping settings]

With the *Clip End* set to 1000m it looks like this:

[image: Fixed]

I'm no sure if you intended to scale your models that large. Perhaps it would be a good idea to scale all of them down. Your ball is currently 5.77m in diameter.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much!